# Find an element with unchecked checkbox and remove its ancestor

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

**My HTML**

```
<div class="apartment-entry-container">
  <table>
    <tr>
     <td>
        Description
        <input type="checkbox">
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="apartment-entry-container">
  <table>
    <tr>
     <td>
        Description
        <input type="checkbox">
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div><span class="hidenone">Click Here To Hide</div>
```

**MY jQuery**

```
 jQuery('.hidenone').click(function(){
           jQuery('.apartment-entry-container  input:not(:checked)').each(function() {
                  jQuery(this).parent('.apartment-entry-container').remove();
                });
            });
```

Good evening. 
I have a list of entities on a page where the user will select the entites they want to include in the coming function. They will include these entites by clicking the checkbox in each .apartment-entry-container.

What I need to do before however is remove all the entites that do not have a checked checkbox. 
My code is removing all of the entities checked or not.

Comment: _"My code is removing all of the entities checked or not."_ I'm pretty sure that won't happen based on the code you posted. You also forgot to close your span.

Comment: `$(this).parent('.apartment-entry-container')` won't select anything. The parent of the checkbox is the `<td>`, not the DIV. So I don't see how this code could be removing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

https://jsfiddle.net/n28uxcny/

```
$(".hidenone").click(function() {

    $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {

    $(this).closest('.apartment-entry-container').remove();

});
```

});

Answer (score 2):

`.parent()` only looks at the parent of an element and in your case that's the `<td>` of the input. You can use `.closest()` instead which traverses up the DOM until it finds a match. So use:

```
jQuery(this).closest('.apartment-entry-container').remove();
```

```js
jQuery('.hidenone').click(function() {
  jQuery('.apartment-entry-container  input:not(:checked)').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).closest('.apartment-entry-container').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apartment-entry-container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Description
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="apartment-entry-container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Description
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div><span class="hidenone">Click Here To Hide</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest and easiest way to tackle this in my opinion. You don't have to target just the checkboxes that are checked. Instead, target all of them and loop through them. For each one, just check the `this.checked` value. If it's false, remove it from the list. Easy as cake

**Here's a JS Bin for you**: http://jsbin.com/rigufazela/edit?html,console,output

```
   <div class="apartment-entry-container">
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
          Description
          <input type="checkbox">
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="apartment-entry-container">
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
          Description
          <input type="checkbox">
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div><span class="hidenone">Click Here To Hide</div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".hidenone").click(function() {

        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, it) {
          if (!this.checked) {
            $(this).parent().remove();
          }
        });

      });

    });
  </script>
```